# 'Google.YouTube.Video.Tags' is not supported by the language

Tags: c#, youtube-api, google-data

When i compile I am getting this error (c#):

> 'Google.YouTube.Video.Tags' is not supported by the language

```
Video video = new Video();
    video.Title = txtTitle.Text;
    video.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory(cmbCat.SelectedItem.ToString(),YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema ));
```

What is the reason for this error ?

Comment: What is the declaration of `Google.YouTube.Video.Tags`? It seems you may be trying to use that property in a manner that C# doesn't support. A precise work-around would depend on what the actual declaration is.

Answer (score 0):

For Google API v3, the correct parameter for **video.Tags.Add** is a **string** parameter. **MediaCategory** is not a valid data type for the **Add** Method of the **Tags** property.

```
video.Tags.Add("Keyword1");
video.Tags.Add("Keyword2");
video.Tags.Add("Keyword3");
```

or

```
video.Tags=new string[] {"Keyword1","Keyword2","Keyword3"};
```

See Google's sample at [UploadVideo.cs](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/dotnet/UploadVideo.cs)